# Angular Testing Dependency Injection of MAT_DIALOG_DATA

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an app component like this and I want to write a unit test for this.

```
   export class AppComponent {
        public errorCode = new BehaviorSubject<number | null>(null);
        public isLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

        constructor(
            public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NotificationDeleteDialogComponent>,
            private notificationService: NotificationService,
            @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
        ) { }
}
```

How can I do DI, I mean how can I import these constructor classes into a test file and Inject the data.

Thank you

Comment: You should add your spec file and show how far you got yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to provide your constructor arguments in your TestBed, like this:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AppComponent ],
        providers: [
            { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: { close: () => {} } },
            { provide: notificationService, useValue: mockedNotificationService},
            { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: mockedDialogData },
        ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    matDialogRef = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MatDialogRef);
    notificationService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NotificationService);

    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Do not forget to declare `mockedNotificationService` and `mockedDialogData` with whatever is needed in the test.